# Why won't Ubuntu 14.04 dual-boot with Win 7?

Tags: dual-boot, 14.04, system-installation

Recently I've tried to install Ubuntu 14.04 lts as a dual-boot to Windows 7. Everything went great until it got to the installation types. It said that it didn't detect any other OS. How do I get the option to install along side existing OS?

Comment: When you say "alongside Windows 7," do you mean the Wubi installation where it actually installs itself within the Windows filesystem? Didn't they deprecate that a few releases back? EDIT: Dumb question, it's still on the ISO's, so it's probably not discontinued...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've noticed the same thing happen when trying to install along side Windows 8, The easiest solution for me was to just shrink the partition of the C: drive in windows, and install Ubuntu on that newest partition, without Ubuntu trying to read the "Along Side Windows Feature"